# PHP storing session data, storing userid in session

Tags: php, session, userid, storing-data

Sorry but I'm new to this. The following code only displays 'Please login'. Code does work but it's not doing what I want it to, I'm trying to store userid in a session. Here is my code

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();


    if(isset($_POST['userid'])){
         $userid = $_POST['userid']; 
         $_SESSION['userid']=$userid;
         echo "Welcome $_SESSION[userid]";
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
        echo "Please login";
        exit;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please show your form code

Comment: Typo `echo "Welcome $_SESSION[userid]";` must be `echo "Welcome $_SESSION['userid']";` it won't solve your problem

Comment: Hei @r33drum why you changed the correct answer to another answer after some time and down voted my answer since it is working?

Comment: @Sanjay Kumar N S I cant vote, I don't have 15 rep, I used your code and it worked, I appreciate it, I gave you the correct answer.

Comment: @r33drum now it came.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

session_start() should be at the beginning without any condition. And also one extra closing bracket ) in the second if condition statement. Try this:

```
 <?php
   session_start();


        if(isset($_POST['userid'])){
            $_SESSION['userid']= $_POST['userid'];
            echo "Welcome {$_SESSION['userid']}";
        }

        if (!$_SESSION['userid']){
            echo "Please login";
            exit;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`session_start();` shouldn't be in your if condition, it has to be at the beginning of the script and always launched

```
<?php

    session_start();


    if(isset($_POST['userid'])){
        $_SESSION['userid']= $_POST['userid'];
        echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['userid'];
    }

    if (!$_SESSION['userid']){
        echo "Please login";
        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- session_start() need to be before you start to work with session.
- I suggest you to replace isset() by empty(), because empty() checked for:

  - "" (an empty string)
  - 0 (0 as an integer)
  - 0.0 (0 as a float)
  - "0" (0 as a string)
  - NULL
  - FALSE
  - array() (an empty array)
  - $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)